# swift ボタンを押した時、delegate通知させるはずがボタンが反応しない

Tags: swift, delegate

今、表示したボタンを押したらdelegateパターンを使いGameSceneクラスのtouchUpButton()が呼び出されるようにしたいのですがその通りに動きません。
デリゲートのあたりは間違えていないと思い、多分upButton.addtargetの部分が
間違えている気がするのですが、修正方法がわかりません。

修正方法を教えて欲しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

protocol touchButtonDelegate{
    func touchUpButton()
}

class Button: NSObject {

    var delegate:touchButtonDelegate?

    func createUpButton() -> UIButton{
        let upButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        upButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "UPButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        upButton.frame = CGRectMake(60, 200, 70, 70)
        upButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Button.pushUpButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return upButton
    }

    func pushUpButton(){
        delegate?.touchUpButton()
    }
}

import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene,touchButtonDelegate{

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        createButton()
    }
    func createButton(){
        let button = Button()
        button.delegate = self
        let upButton = button.createUpButton()

        self.view?.addSubview(upButton)
    }
    func touchUpButton() {
       print("文字表示しました")
    }


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */


}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

}

Comment: あなたのコード中、`createButton()`メソッドの中でローカル変数`button`を`let button = Button()`という形で宣言していますが、ここで作成された`Button`クラスのインスタンスは、`createButton()`メソッドが終了すれば解放されてしまいます。`UIButton`で`.TouchUpInside`のイベントが発生した時にはtargetとなるオブジェクトが解放された後なので、そのイベントは黙って無視される、という形になっているものと思われます。(Swift2のコードはすぐに試せないので、長ったらしいコメントですみません。)ちなみに、あなたのコード、コーディングが面倒になる上に、バグが入りやすい(実際にバグっている…)と言う、「delegateパターンにするメリットが何もない」状態のコードになっています。action-targetパターンで動作する`UIButton`クラスをなぜ無理にdelegateパターンにはめようとするのか、全く動機がわかりません。今後高機能な`UIButton`のサブクラスでも作るつもりがないのであれば、無理にdelegateパターンにするのはやめておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました！delegateパターンを使いっていれば問題ない、と思っていて使ってしまっていました。

Comment: 解決の報告ありがとうございます。どんなデザインパターンにも長所短所があるわけなので、色々試しながら見極めていかれるのは良いことだろうと思います。出来ましたら、お時間をとって回答の形で解決方法を書いてみてください。